# IPC using message queue in C: Error in receiving

Tags: c, linux, ipc, message-queue

I am implementing message queue in C linux. I am sending an `integer = 17` and receiving `integer = 0`. Please see below and let me know what's wrong with my `msgsnd` and `msgrcv` functions. 
Please give attention to this: will `rbuf` store data in `rbuf->m->msglen` or in `rbuf->mtype`.

In sending process

```
msgsnd(msqid, sbuf,sizeof(int), 0);
printf("\nmsglen = %d",rbuf->m->msglen);  // 17
```

In receiving process. Both have same msqid. I have verified it.

```
msgrcv(msqid, rbuf, sizeof(int), 1, 0);
printf("\nmsglen = %d",rbuf->m->msglen); // 0

//msqid=98305, some valid id
```

here is my struct definations defined in another file.

```
typedef struct message1
{
    int msglen;
    unsigned char *cp;
}msg1;

typedef struct msgbuf
{
    long    mtype;
    msg1    *m;
} message_buf;
```

Comment: What is the `errno` value after the `msgrcv()` call?

Comment: no. of bytes received

Comment: Sorry, i updated my comment with the proper question. What's the errno value?

Comment: Please show whole code

Comment: In sending process you are printing `rbuf->m->msglen` - shouldn't that be sbuf, the message you just sent?

Comment: @harmic ohh that's just typing mistake. I checked it by debugger. and it's was showing 17 only.

Comment: @user3436838: what is the `errno` after calling `msgrcv()`?

Comment: @Lawrence there is no error. I have even put the whole code as a answer. If you want you can see this or even run this onto your system. Thanks... :)

Comment: @RahulRDhobi I have put the full code as answer to my question. Please see this and let me know the error. Thanks.. :) I know it's a bit lengthy but since you asked it, so here it is for you.

Comment: @user3436838: its good that you pasted the code, but please put it in your question, not as a new answer.

Comment: @Lawrence I would do it once it's corrected. It was a bit lengthy so didn't do that so that geeks here just don't ignore it. I really need to get it done now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a message which contains a pointer to your message1 struct. The receiving process dereferences that pointer, but in that process it does not point to the same thing. In fact I am surprised you didn't get a segfault.

You should define msgbuf like this:

```
typedef struct msgbuf
{
    long    mtype;
    msg1    m;
} message_buf;
```

So that the msg1 struct is contained within the msgbuf rather than pointed to by it.

Also, the size you need to specify is sizeof(message_buf), not sizeof(int).

Comment: Both processes are on the same machine. I am a student so was just trying it. 
and I did sizeof(int) because I wanted to receive the length of my message first, so that I could allocate space for cp in the receiving process and then receive cp.

Comment: @user3436838 It does not matter if they are on the same machine. Different processes are not able to access each others memory.

Comment: Thanks sir. It's working. But the problem is : I first wanted to send msglen, which is sent successfully and then I want to send cp. I have allocated space for cp as **rbuf->m.cp=malloc(rbuf->m.msglen);** 
 and then **msgrcv(msqid,rbuf,rbuf->m.msglen,1,0)** It's giving seg fault. Any idea about it.

Comment: @user3436838 same problem. You cannot send any pointers, such as returned by malloc.

Comment: You can but you have to send the whole thing within the msgbuf structure. Allocate enough space for the msgbuf and its embedded array content.

Comment: I have initialised cp="do you know?" in the server's process and **(msgsnd(msqid, sbuf,len, 0)** that's how I am sending it. len is len is length of cp.

Comment: **msgsnd(msqid, sbuf,sizeof(int)+len, 0);** in server's process

**rbuf=malloc(150);
 rbuf->m.cp=malloc(100);
msgrcv(msqid, rbuf,104, 1, 0)**  in receiver's process
it's also giving seg fault in receiving process.

Answer (score 0):

```
//header files
#include"msgbuf.h"  //where I have put my structures
#define AUTOMATIC 1
#define USER_DATA 2

int main()
{
    int msgflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666,ch,len=0;
    size_t msgsize = 0;
    int msqid;
    key_t key;
    message_buf *sbuf;
    char ans;
    char *data;
    key = ftok("/home/user",15);

    printf("Do you want to send messages\t");
    scanf("%c",&ans);
    getchar();
    if (((ans=='y' || ans=='Y') && (msqid = msgget(key, msgflg )) ==-1))
    {       perror("msgget");
            exit(1);
    }
    else
    fprintf(stderr,"msgget: msgget succeeded: msqid = %d\n", msqid);

    while(ans=='y' || ans=='Y')
    {
            printf("\n1. Automatic data\n2. Enter data\n3. Exit\nEnter your choice\t");
            scanf("%d",&ch);
            getchar();
            switch(ch)
            {
                    case AUTOMATIC: len=strlen("Did you get this?");

                                    sbuf=malloc(len+sizeof(int));
                                    memset(sbuf, 0, sizeof(message_buf));
                                    sbuf->m=malloc(len+sizeof(int));
                                    memset(sbuf->m, 0, sizeof(msg1));

                                    sbuf->m->msglen=len;
                                    sbuf->m->cp=malloc(sizeof(len));
                                    strncpy(sbuf->m->cp, "Did you get this?",strlen("Did you get this?"));
                                    sbuf->m->cp[strlen(sbuf->m->cp)]='\0';
                                    break;
                    case USER_DATA: printf("\nEnter data\t");
                                    fflush(stdout);
                                    len = getline(&data, &msgsize, stdin);

                                    sbuf=malloc(len+sizeof(int));
                                    memset(sbuf, 0, sizeof(message_buf));
                                    sbuf->m=malloc(len+sizeof(int));
                                    memset(sbuf->m, 0, sizeof(msg1));

                                    strcpy(sbuf->m->cp, data);
                                    sbuf->m->cp[strlen(sbuf->m->cp)]='\0';
                                    sbuf->m->msglen=len;
                                    break;
                    case 3: msgctl(msqid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
                            printf("\nQueue with q id = %d is removed\n",msqid);
                            exit(1);
                    default:printf("\nTRY AGAIN\t");
                            scanf("%c",&ans);
                            getchar();
            }
            printf("\nmsglen = %d\nmsgcp= %s",sbuf->m->msglen,sbuf->m->cp);
             /* Send a message */
            sbuf->mtype=1;
            if (msgsnd(msqid, sbuf,2*sizeof(int), 0) < 0)
            {
        printf("Msg q id= %d\nMsg type= %d\nMsg Text %s\nMsg Len= %d\n", msqid, sbuf->mtype, sbuf->m->cp,sbuf->m->msglen);
                    perror("msgsnd");
                    exit(1);
            }
            else
            printf("\nMessage: %s\n Sent\n", sbuf->m->cp);
    }
    msgctl(msqid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    printf("\nQueue with q id = %d is removed\n",msqid);
    return 0;
}
```

Now Receiving code

```
//header files
#include"msgbuf.h"
int main()
{
    int msqid;
    key_t key;
    int msgflg = 0666;
    message_buf  *rbuf;
    int msg_len_rcvd=0;

    rbuf=malloc(150);
    rbuf->m=malloc(100);
    key = ftok("/home/user",15);
    if ((msqid = msgget(key, msgflg)) ==-1)
    {
            perror("msgget");
            exit(1);
    }
    printf("\n\n%d\n",msqid);
    /* Receive an answer of message type 1.   */
    while(1)
    {
            if ( (msg_len_rcvd=msgrcv(msqid, rbuf, 2*sizeof(int), 1, 0)) < 0)
            {
                    perror("msgrcv");
                    exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                    printf("\n Number of bytes received:: %d", msg_len_rcvd);
                    printf("\nmtype1 = %d",rbuf->mtype);
                    printf("\nmsglen= %d",rbuf->m->msglen);
            }
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```